# Arreglo de strings

Tags: c, array, string

Buenas noches comunidad, sigo en mis batallas con el lenguaje `c`, ayer en asignar memoria a una matriz de enteros, pero hoy me he topado con la necesidad de trabajar un Array de strings. El ejercicio consiste en crear una arreglo de `N` posiciones donde se almacenan nombres que deben ser ingresados por consola, el código que he hecho es el siguiente:

```
int numeroEmpleados = 0;
char *empleados = NULL;

void inicializarEstructuras();
void llenadoDeDatos();

int main(){
  inicializarEstructuras();
  llenadoDeDatos();
  imprimirDatos();
  return 0;
}

void inicializarEstructuras(){
  printf("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados: ");
  scanf("%d", &numeroEmpleados);
  //Reserva de memoria para los vectores y matrices
  empleados = (char*)malloc(numeroEmpleados*sizeof(char));
}

void llenadoDeDatos(){
  //Se solicitan los nombres de los empleados
  for(int i = 0; i < numeroEmpleados; i++){
    printf("Ingrese el nombre para el empleado [ %d ]: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%s", &empleados[i]);
  }
}

void imprimirDatos(){
  for(int i = 0; i < numeroEmpleados; i++){
    printf("empleado %s", empleados[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Sin embargo el código compila con `warnings`

```
empresa.cpp: In function ‘void imprimirDatos()’:
empresa.cpp:75:37: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
printf("empleado %s", empleados[i]);
```

Y al ejecutar el programa se presenta error de `segmentation fault` al almacenar alguno de los nombres ingresados.

El ejercicio es académico pero me ha dado bola toda la tarde. Gracias

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas @eferion y @Marco Ramírez, han sido de mucha ayuda en el entendimiento de manejo de strings en `C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `strlen` y `strcpy` de la siguiente forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int numeroEmpleados = 0;
char **empleados = NULL;

void inicializarEstructuras();
void llenadoDeDatos();

int main()
{
   inicializarEstructuras();
   llenadoDeDatos();
   imprimirDatos();
   return 0;
}

void inicializarEstructuras()
{
     printf("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados: ");
     scanf("%d", &numeroEmpleados);
    //Reserva de memoria para los vectores y matrices
     empleados = (char*)malloc(numeroEmpleados*sizeof(char));
}

void llenadoDeDatos()
{
    char nombre_empleado_temp[30] = {0};

    //Se solicitan los nombres de los empleados
    for(int i = 0; i < numeroEmpleados; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese el nombre para el empleado [ %d ]: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", &nombre_empleado_temp);
        empleados[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(nombre_empleado_temp)*sizeof(char) + 1);
        strcpy(empleados[i], nombre_empleado_temp);
    }
}

void imprimirDatos()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numeroEmpleados; i++)
    {
        printf("empleado %s", (char*)(empleados[i]));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

En esta implementación en particular estarás todavía limitado por los 30 caracteres que están `nombre_empleado_temp`sin embargo, este arreglo existirá de manera temporal dado que es una variable automática definida en la función `llenadoDeDatos()`

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, les cuento que después de revolcar la red y hacer un número finitos de cambios a mi código lo he solucionado, aunque me queda faltando una parte (no es muy importante para el ejercicio) ya he podido almacenar y leer un arreglo de strings

Los cambios que realice fueron los siguientes:

Declarar el arregllo como una matriz

```
char **empleados = NULL;
```

La reserva de memoria de igual forma

```
 empleados = (char**)malloc(numeroEmpleados*sizeof(char*));
```

Y al momento de leer los nombres de entrada reservo memoria para la posicion donde se va a guardar el nombre ingresado

```
empleados[i] = (char*)malloc(10);
scanf("%s", empleados[i]);
```

Aquí es donde me queda lo pendiente, como hacer para que el tamaño reservado no sea fijo `(10)` si no que se dimensione de acuerdo al número de carácteres ingresados por el usuario.

El código completo lo dejo a continuación:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

char **empleados = NULL;
int numeroEmpleados = 0;

void inicializarEstructuras();
void llenadoDeDatos();
void imprimirDatos();

int main(){
  inicializarEstructuras();
  llenadoDeDatos();
  imprimirDatos();
  return 0;
}

void inicializarEstructuras(){
  printf("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados: ");
  scanf("%d", &numeroEmpleados);

  //Reserva de memoria para los vectores y matrices
  empleados = (char**)malloc(numeroEmpleados*sizeof(char*));    
}

void llenadoDeDatos(){
  //Se solicitan los nombres de los empleados
  for(int i = 0; i < numeroEmpleados; i++){
    printf("Ingrese el nombre para el empleado [ %d ]: ", i + 1);
    empleados[i] = (char*)malloc(10);
    scanf("%s", empleados[i]);
  }
}

void imprimirDatos(){
  for(int empleado = 0; empleado < numeroEmpleados; empleado++){
    printf("empleado %s", empleados[empleado]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Respondiendo a la duda de tu propia [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/117196/463):

> Aquí es donde me queda lo pendiente, como hacer para que el tamaño reservado no sea fijo (10) si no que se dimensione de acuerdo al número de carácteres ingresados por el usuario.

Puedes optar por, como te ha comentado [@MarcoRamírez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/117198/463), por usar un buffer de tamaño suficiente para cubrir las necesidades:

```
char buffer[200]; // o 1000 o ... lo que necesites, que sea lo suficientemente grande
scanf("%s", &buffer);
empleados[i] = malloc(strlen(nombre_empleado_temp)*sizeof(char) + 1);
strcpy(empleados[i],buffer);
```

Si eso no satisface tus ansias de precisión porque piensas que aun así se puede quedar corto, puedes optar por leer la secuencia a *trozos* y hacer reservas de memoria a conveniencia:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* ReadLine()
{
  char* buffer = 0;
  int reserved_length = 0;
  int length = 0;

  do
  {
    char c = getchar();
    if( c == '\n' ) break;

    if( reserved_length == length )
    {
      reserved_length += 5; // por poner una cantidad...
      buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer,reserved_length);
    }

    buffer[length] = c;
    length++;
  } while( !feof(stdin) );

  buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer,length);
  buffer[length] = 0;

  return buffer;
}

int main()
{
  char* buffer = ReadLine();
  printf("%s\n",buffer);
  free(buffer);
}
```

La última reserva se hace para ajustar exactamente el tamaño de la reserva para no desperdiciar ningún byte... ya que nos ponemos quisquillosos llegamos hasta el final.